# Adding a new taxonomy term from a custom content type field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, nodes

Is it possible to automatically add a new taxonomy term (related to certain vocabulary) from a field in a custom content type; so when submitting a new content entry (related to that custom content type) I add a new taxonomy term related to that entry to create a richer tagging functionality by time for future entries?

Comment: Add a new taxonomy to what ?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @tostinni: to a taxonomy vocabulary that already exists.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [taxonomy_save_term()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_save_term/6). Here's an example from the comments:

```
$term = array(
'vid' => 5, // Voacabulary ID
'name' => 'Drupal', // Term Name
'synonyms' => 'Druplet', // (Optional) Synonym of this term
'parent' => 11, // (Optional) Term ID of a parent term 
'relations' => array(15), // (Optional) Related Term IDs
);

taxonomy_save_term($term);
```

You could use this inside [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) on the operations `insert` or `presave` (and `update`). See the comments at the first link for more info.

EDIT: For drupal 7 you have to check out the [node api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/7) instead of of hook_nodeapi().

Comment: Any orientations specific to Drupal 7.

Comment: Actually I found this for Drupal 7: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7. Thanks for the tip.